# EclipseLink, JPA, Mysql turn off Autocommit

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, eclipselink

I am having problems with MySQL getting every row committed when I do entityManager.persist();

I have tried with

```
JPAConnect.em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
```

Without any luck.

Or is there a way to commit a List<> without having to loop through every row?

```
jpac.beginTransaction();

        for (BuyLateStrategyEntity buyLateEntity : buyLateList) {
            stockName = buyLateEntity.getStockName();

            freader.readRawData(stockName, buyLateEntity.getTradeDate());


            //persist() done here.
            runningTotal *= findSalePrice(buyLateEntity.getClosePrice());

            System.out.println("Running total: " + runningTotal + " At Date: " + 
            buyLateEntity.getTradeDate() + " Instrument: " + buyLateEntity.getStockName());
        }
        jpac.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: You have a few answers below, but I'm not clear on the actual problem you are encountering.  What is the problem - are rows not being inserted?  If so, check that your transaction is associated to your EntityManager correctly.  Show us more on how you configured this if you are unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that the rows hit you DB in a particular order, the only way to solve is flushing. Just read the documentation of the `FlushModeType` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html) and you will understand that it affects actually the flush time in combination with executing a Query, and not in combination of other `persist()` calls.

If you just want that the rows hit the DB in any particular order, I would simply call `em.persist()/merge()` for every row (*which in your code is missing*), but `flush()` ONCE before the commit (although a flush would happen automatically on transaction commit).

But if your idea was to flush every row: are you trying to solve the correct problem : why would you need flushing in a `for` loop? May be you simply need a sorting parameter (JPA can do that for you if that list is a field in another entity)? Keep in mind, that even if you flush an entry, the result is not visible to other transactions until you commit (given a reasonable transaction isolation and a Storage engine that supports transactions, like InnoDB).

---

**UPDATE** (after you made it clear that you want as less communication as possible with your DB)

You are already doing your best, by committing (therefore flushing) only once. As a side note: in EclipseLink there is support for [Batch Write](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Optimizing_the_EclipseLink_Application_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Use_Batch_Writing_for_Optimization) which you can enable, if your DB supports that. The problem is that MySQL has support only for batch inserts, and not for updates, so you shouldn't enable it.

Comment: I am trying to do exactly the opposite. Committing as many rows as possible from a List<> in one single call.

Comment: updated my answer. Note that simply calling merge() or persist() does not mean that anything is necessarily sent to DB. Usually EclipseLink can decide that alone.

Comment: You are right. It seems like it has some kind of logic for this. Which is kind of annoying since it leads to inconsistent speed if it chooses single row commit on a persist() call or wait until .commit()